# xlookup function in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that I need to retrieve data from, but I also want to add a new column (researchIDName) which would display the names from column companyname, based on the ID from column researchID.

In excel an xlookup would be suffice for this, but I was wondering if there is a way to include this in my current SQL script?

I have included below my current script and how the tables look like.

```
SELECT c1.SID, c1.FID, c1.companyname, 
       C1.parentID, c1.parentname, c1.companytype,
       c1.companystatus, c2.researchID,
FROM c2 left join
     c1 
     on c2.SID = c1.SID
```

[image]

*Edit
Following Gordon's comments, the below script works in joining the two tables, but now I require this script to add an extra column named 'researchIDName'.

```
SELECT c1.SID, c1.FID, c1.companyname, 
       C1.parentID, c1.parentname, c1.companytype,
       c1.companystatus, c2.researchID
FROM c1 LEFT JOIN
     c2 
     ON c2.SID = c1.SID
```

Normally in Excel, I would use the below xlookup formula to add data to 'researchIDName' column. My question is how I can add this extra column in SQL.

```
XLOOKUP(researchID, c2.SID, C2.Companyname)
```

**Edit.. To simplify the tables, I have included an updated image below (with an extra table c0). Therefore, now I have 3 tables from which I would like to see SID, FID, Comments, Companyname, ResearchID all together, with an extra column named 'ResearchIDName'. In excel, I would just use an xlookup function to look for the researchID and then to retrieve the companyname related to it from table c2. Please see below script done so far and let me know what should I add in order to add this ResearchIDName column into my results.

[Tables as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXiDF.png)

Select c0.FID, c0.Comments, c1.sid, c2.Companyname, c2.ResearchID, ResearchIDName
From c0
Left join c1 On c1.FID=c0.FID
Left join c2 On c2.SID=b2.SID

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is basically correct.  The only issue is that you probably want all rows from `c1` with the extra column from `c2`.  For that, the `c1` table should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c1.SID, c1.FID, c1.companyname, 
       C1.parentID, c1.parentname, c1.companytype,
       c1.companystatus, c2.researchID
FROM c1 LEFT JOIN
     c2 
     ON c2.SID = c1.SID
```

I also removed a lingering comma before the `FROM` clause.

Of course, if all `SID`s in `c1` are populated with correct values, then you don't need an outer join at all.  In that case, the ordering of `c1`/`c2` in the `FROM` clause doesn't matter.

EDIT:

If you want the name associated with the `researchId`, you would use another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c1.SID, c1.FID, c1.companyname, 
       C1.parentID, c1.parentname, c1.companytype,
       c1.companystatus, c2.researchID,
       c2r.companyName
FROM c1 LEFT JOIN
     c2 
     ON c2.SID = c1.SID LEFT JOIN
     c2 c2r
     ON c2r.SID = c2.ResarchID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have rectified this. But apart from this join, I would also need to create a new column named 'researchIDName' and to have values in there from the c1.companyname, depending on the c2.researchID. All the values from c2.researchID would appear in c1.SID and I would like this extra column (researchIDName) to show the names for these values from c2.researchID. Each company ID (SID) may have its own researchID or another company's researchID or it may not have any and in this case it will show Nulls. Do you have any suggestion on how to add this extra column?

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru It would likely help if you could edit your original question and include your existing schema.  I don't understand why you need another column.  Does c1 already have a researchid?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please have a look at my original question at the very end where is this link: ![enter image description here] 1. If you click on 1, you would be able to see an image of how my tables and how my results should look like. C1 does not have a researchID, only C2 has. However the IDs found in researchID column can also be found in SID column from the 1st table and I would need to retrieve their names, in an extra column. Not all companies have a researchID company linked to them, but this is fine. A Null would be suffice in this case.

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru . . . If you want to look up the name based on the `researchId`, you need another `JOIN` -- I added that to this answer.  But your image really doesn't explain your problem.  And your question could do a better job.  It is better to put sample data and desired results in the question *as text tables*.

Comment: @ GordonLinoff I can see you have added c2r, but this table does not exist. There are only two tables as shown in my picture, the third tables represents how the results of my query should look like. I can only add these tables as a picture, I don't know how to add the tables as text in my question box.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  This is how the xlookup function would look like in Excel for the column 'researchIDName': XLOOKUP(c2.researchID, c2.SID, C2.Companyname).