# Using SQL as an xlookup

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables that I need to retrieve data from + I also need an additional column (ResearchIDName) acting like an xlookup from the c2 table. I have created the below script so far on how to retrieve the data needed from the 3 tables and I have attached an image on how my tables look like and how my results should be, but I need help on this additional column (ResearchIDName). The xlookup formula for ResearchIDName would be: XLOOKUP(O3,I:I,H:H). All the research IDs would be present in the SID column in table c2 and the Companynames column refers to the SID column so all I would need would be to have this separate column mentioning the name of the research ID company. Do you have any suggestions?

*Edit The result of the ResearchIDName would be to search in all the SIDs and to retrieve the name from the companyname. Each SID has a different ResearchID. The SID name can be McDonalds, whereas its Research name would be KFC. Companyname in the results currently shows the company name of the SID, I also need the company name of the Research ID.

Table c0

```
+-----+----------+ 
| FID | Comments |
+-----+----------+
| g17 | Food     |
| h11 | Retail   |
| j12 | Banks    |
```

Table c1

```
+-------+-----+
|  SID  | FID |
+-------+-----+
| 12345 | g17 |
| 34567 | h11 |
| 56152 | j12 |
+-------+-----+
```

Table c2

```
+-------+-------------+------------+
|  SID  | Companyname | ResearchID |
+-------+-------------+------------+
| 12345 | McDonalds   |      67789 |
| 34567 | Sainsbury's |      37832 |
| 56152 | Barclays    |            |
+-------+-------------+------------+
```

Desired Results

```
+-------+-----+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|  SID  | FID | Comments | Companyname | ResearchID | ResearchIDName |
+-------+-----+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| 12345 | g17 | Food     | McDonalds   |      29182 | KFC            |
| 34567 | h11 | Retail   | Sainsbury's |      91821 | Tesco          |
| 56152 | j12 | Banks    | Barclays    |            |                |
+-------+-----+----------+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

[My 3 tables and my desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuFA.jpg)

```
Select c0.FID, c0.Comments,

c1.sid,

c2.Companyname, c2.ResearchID,

ResearchIDName

From c0

Left join c1 On c1.FID=c0.FID

Left join c2 On c2.SID=c1.SID
```

**EDIT The script as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name works if the ResearchID is an integer column. In my case, it was a varchar and this is why I kept getting errors. But the below adjustments work (adding "::varchar" after "on r.sid = c2.ResearchID")

```
Select c0.FID, 
       c0.Comments,
       c1.sid,
       c2.Companyname, 
       c2.ResearchID,
       r.companyname as research_company_name
From c0
  Left join c1 on c1.FID = c0.FID
  Left join c2 on c2.sid = c1.sid
  left join c2 as r on r.sid = c2.researchid::varchar
```

Comment: How is this different to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637084/xlookup-function-in-sql)

Comment: It's in a cleaner format, as I kept getting feedback that they do not understand my question and then when I re-edited, they all went silent. I would appreciate a helpful response on this.

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru that's what happens when you post an unclear question. This question is still unclear : `xlookup` is not a SQL or even a programming term. In Excel it's a function that simply queries a range, so your question essentially says `I want to run a query`. What are those tables, what do they contain, what results do you expect and what's the problem right now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xlookup function in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637084/xlookup-function-in-sql)

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru in fact, this is *worse* than the previous question. This one contains no data at all, no explanation what you want. Not even an image *in the question itself*. Although images can't be copied or queried, so that wouldn't help if you need a complex query. `I want SQL to act like XLOOKUP` means very little, as a `SELECT` query does just that - search and return data. Do you want to join two tables? Or find user-supplied matches in a table?

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru you didn't provide any tables. There are no images in the *question*. And images can't be queried. Gordon Linoff went to a lot of trouble to try and help you. I'd say ignoring him and complaining he `went silent` after 2 hours is disrespectful at least.

Comment: I do not have the right yet to include full images into my post, all I have is that link above (My 3 tables and my desired results) in my question which takes you to an image.

Comment: DON'T ADD IMAGES. They can't be copied, can't be queried. Post *text* at least. The `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` queries would be better, allowing people to experiment with your data. Don't ask for people to type your data.

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru in fact, it looks like Gordon Linoff already answered your question but you didn't try it. Your last two comments suggest you didn't even try executing the query. `c2r` is an alias, not a table name

Comment: How do you know I did not try it? I got the below error.SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1010

Comment: Can you please explain where the values for the `ResearchIDName` come from? They don't seem to be part of the three tables you are joining. Do you have a mapping table that contains that? Also: I find examples using generic names like `c0` or `c1` much harder to read and understand than table names like `company` or `food_comments`

Comment: The values from ResearchIDName should come from Companyname, depending on the ResearchID. KFC and Tesco don't appear in Companyname now, because I didn't want to add too many lines, but basically any ResearchIDs can also be found in SID. The Companyname refers to the SID, so I need to have the ResearchIDName displayed. I have a database with companies (SID Ids) and for each company, I need to research a different one, hence why there is this ResearchID column. ResearchIDName is not a column that exists in any of my tables so I need to create it in my query results somehow, without alter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `KFC` and `Tesco` are also stored somewhere in the `c2` table (which you didn't show, so I have to guess), then I would assume you just need another join:

```
Select c0.FID, 
       c0.Comments,
       c1.sid,
       c2.Companyname, 
       c2.ResearchID,
       r.companyname as research_company_name
From c0
  Left join c1 on c1.FID = c0.FID
  Left join c2 on c2.sid = c1.sid --<< changed from your original query
  left join c2 as r on r.sid = c2.researchid --<< this finds a company that matches the researchid column
```

Your query contains the join condition `on c2.SID = b2.SID` which would result in an error as you don't have an alias `b2` in your example. My guess is that you meant `c2.sid = c1.sid`

Comment: Thanks, I have amended this and ran it as you suggested but I get this error now: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1032

Comment: @RuxandraDumitru The despite what your sample data shows us, `reasearchid` doesn't seem to be an integer column (or `sid`). An ugly workaround is to cast the column in the join condition. But you should really fix broken design. **NEVER**, ever store numbers in `text` columns.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked my Database Architect to fix this column as an integer. He said he is not able to, because we are sometimes getting 'empty strings' in 'researchid' column. He is advising me to use explicit type casts. I will come back to you once I am able to find a solution to this.

Comment: "empty values" should be stored as `NULL` in an integer column. Doesn't sound as if your "architect" is very experienced in this.

Comment: I have told him what you suggested but he said that this is how the data comes from a different platform (as strings) and he is not able to set them up as 'nulls' because the data will override with each update made... I am thinking with my colleagues what else we can do.

Comment: Well, if you have empty strings in that column, the cast will also throw an error. Storing those numbers in an `integer` column is the only sensible solution. The import needs to be adjusted to handle that

Comment: So he is not able to change the column into integer (with empty values as nulls), because the data keeps overriding with each update, as per his explanation. But I have found another way, to add "::varchar" after "on r.sid = c2.researchid" and it is working like this. I will edit my question with this update. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yes, I know that is the right way to do it, but I do not want to come across as too agressive to the Architect, especially as I am new to SQL. I have noted this down and when I bump into several other issues I will raise all of these with his manager, as improvements to the database flow.